# this.connection.getMetadata is not a function

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, typeorm, typegraphql, typeorm-datamapper

I have a base graphql resolver that looks like this:

```
import { ClassType, Resolver, Query, UseMiddleware, Mutation, Arg } from 'type-graphql';
import { InjectRepository, OrmManager } from 'typeorm-typedi-extensions';
import { EntityManager } from 'typeorm';
import 'reflect-metadata';
// import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

function baseResolver<
T extends ClassType,
X extends ClassType,
P extends ClassType
>(
    suffix: string,
    returnType: T,
    inputType: X,
    repository: any,
    updateType?: P
): any {
  @Resolver({ isAbstract: true })
    abstract class BaseResolver {
    protected repo: any;

    constructor(@OrmManager() protected entityManager: EntityManager) {
      this.repo = entityManager.getCustomRepository(repository);
    }

    @Query(() => [returnType], { name: `getAll${suffix}` })
    async getAll(): Promise<T[]> {
      return this.repo.find();
    }

    @Mutation(() => returnType, { name: `create${suffix}` })
    async create(@Arg('data', () => inputType) data: any): Promise<T> {
      const result = this.repo.create(data).save();
      return result;
    }

    @Mutation(() => Boolean, { name: `update${suffix}` })
    async update(@Arg('data', () => updateType) data: any) {
      await this.repo.update(data.id, data);
      return true;
    }

    @Mutation(() => Boolean, { name: `delete${suffix}` })
    async delete(@Arg('id') id: string) {
      await this.repo.softDelete(id);
    }
  }

  return BaseResolver;
}

export default baseResolver;
```

I then extend the resolver in other descendant resolvers. When I try to run this, I get the following error(thrown by the constructor):

```
 "TypeError: this.connection.getMetadata is not a function",
```

Can anyone help with this? What could be the issue with this code?

Comment: I got this error a few times and I noticed that it was normally as a result of a package not being installed properly or an argument type not passed in properly. So my advice it check your code to see that there are no syntax or code errors

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`npm install 'reflect-metadata' -D`

Add this to your `tsconfig.json`:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
  "types": ["reflect-metadata"],
  "experimentalDecorators": true
```

Restart VS Code